# Adding pages and templates to a portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using eclipse ide and I have created a liferay project Test-portlet. I haven't written any code for this project
When I ran this project I got the usual welcome screen and I added the Test-portlet to the page and removed other stuff from the page.

I actually want to create a website using liferay. The website already exists which should be rewritten in liferay.

So when I load the project I get this welcome screen and the Test-portlet. At the top of this page I get the the menu-Admin,Sites,.... and LIferay logo on LHS.
I wish to remove all of these and displa only  the web page data of the website. I know I can use themes and layouts for such purpose.

If I should use portlet to create this website , how should I keep adding pages and designs?

Also how should I add pages,themes,templates to this portlet?

Before creating this Test-portlet project, I had created pages using control panel.

How should I create this website? Using portlet by creating project?

EDIT:

Also this Test-portlet is displayed as a small portlet on the entire page. WHen  click on the gear symbol and click on maximise, it only maximises during that time and when project is run again, it comes back to its original size.

Should I create this websiste using portlets?
Data for website comes from database. Few pages have static data.
Subsequent pages may be added in future.

HOw should the pages be added if I use portlet to create the website?

Comment: From the question it is clear that you don't understand what is a portlet and how liferay works with all its different parts. I am sorry but there is no easy way but to learn atleast what is liferay and how portlets work. Please atleast go through the liferay User-guide and more than half of your queries would be answered. And by the way you __cannnot add pages (& page templates) to portlets__.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through liferay themes and liferay layouts